# How to share a data table in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I have a RobotFramework fixture that allows me to run a test against various version of our API...

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template     Can sell through API

*** Test Cases ***      apiVersion
Version 1               1.01
Version 2               2.13
Version 3               3.00

*** Keywords ***
Can sell through API
    [Arguments]    ${apiVersion}
    Given I am using API version {apiVersion}
    When I provide valid details
    Then my sale is confirmed
```

I now want to write more tests using the same list of API version but I do not want to duplicate that list in each test fixture. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
*** Variables ***
@{api_versions}    1.01    2.13    3.00

*** Test Cases ***
First Test Case
[Template]    First Template
    @{api_versions}[0]
    @{api_versions}[1]
    @{api_versions}[2]

Second Test Case
[Template]    Second Template
    @{api_versions}[0]
    @{api_versions}[1]
    @{api_versions}[2]

*** Keywords ***
First Template
    [Arguments]    ${api_version}
    Do Something    ${api_version}

Second Template
    [Arguments]    ${api_version}
    Do Something Different    ${api_version}
```

Or:

```
*** Settings *** 
Test Template    Can Sell Through API
Suite Setup    Set API Versions

*** Test Cases ***
Test 1    @{api_versions}
... 

*** Keywords ***
Set API Versions
    ${api_versions}    Create List    1.01    2.13    3.00
    Set Suite Variable    @{api_versions}

Can Sell Through API
    [Arguments]    @{api_version}
    Do Your Stuff Here With    @{api_versions}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this doesn't really work as expected. The problem is that for each test case there is only one test which combines the output for all API versions. I want one test per API version for each test case so that on failure I want to know immediately which API version as failed.

Comment: OK. Then what about to create Keyword containing `Set Suite Variable    @{api_versions}`, set Suite Setup with that keyword, then define `Test Template` on suite level and then set Test Cases like: `Test Case 1    @{api_versions}` ...

Comment: Not sure what I should be setting `Test Template` to?

Comment: `*** Settings ***`
`Test Template    Can Sell Through API`
`Suite Setup    Set API Versions`
`*** Test Cases ***`
`Test 1    @{api_versions}`
...
`*** Keywords ***`
`Set API Versions`
    `${api_versions}    Create List    1.01    2.13    3.00`
    `Set Suite Variable    @{api_versions}`

`Can Sell Through API`
    `Do Your Stuff Here With    @{api_versions}`
Sorry for the bad formatting.